# How to test if a given string occurred on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to test in my Rails app if given text (for example post content) occurred on a page. I can't just use `assert_select` (or maybe I don't know how to) because site layout will change in the future - and I can't tell today if this text will be wrapped in `p` tag, `h3` tag or whatever. I just need to know if this text occurred. 
In other words, I need functionality like this:

```
assert_match CGI.escape("some text"),        mail.body.encoded
```

but for HTML page.

Comment: If the site layout changes your tests change. Simple as that. Use CSS to make testable pages, that is if this is really important to your testing give it a class that won't change regardless of how it's presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end I found the answer:

```
assert_match /some text/, response.body
```